# Linking the task to the IP address using Python

Tags: networking, python

I don't think anybody has posted this question/idea yet. I want to make a Python script on Linux platform to get IP address of the hosts connected to my computer. Well, this is simple while typing in `netstat -tua` and then I can get a list of TCP or UDP connections, but the problem is that they are not being nice because we (or only I) don't know where exactly the traffic comes from. So I want to link those connections to the programs (tasks) respectively which bring the connections so I can analyze the traffic and get the information more easily. Any idea?

Comment: netstat -aon  do command do tells the process id and you can link it with tcp/udp connectionw